# Looking understand why delegate keep alive

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have the following structure

Main ViewController: it is responsible to call the (A) view controller.
(A) ViewController: create an CustomClass instance and has a delegate for this class.
CustomClass: in each period of 1 second, a message is sent to (A) view controller via delegate.

Until here all works fine. Once I returned to Main ViewController the delegate keep alive, in other words, the delegate updates A(ViewController) variable. I checked that viewDidDisappear of (A) ViewController is called.
When I return again from Main ViewController to (A) ViewController, a new variable instance is created. I don't understand this anyway.

Besides this doubt, I would like to understand why the delegate keep alive when I return to main view controller. I am using a UINavigationItem to navigation.

I am a beginner in IOS development.

Thanks advanced!!!

**Edit 1:**
The (A)ViewController is called from MainViewController by Segue. The segue was added via storyboard.

**MainViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**AViewController.swift**

```
class ScanDevices : UIViewController, CustomClassDelegate {

    var myInts : [Int] = []

    var customClass : CustomClass!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("viewDidLoad")

        if customClass == nil {
            customClass = CustomClass()
            customClass.customClassDelegate = self
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        print("viewWillAppear")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        print("viewDidAppear")
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        print("viewWillDisappear")
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        print("viewDidDisappear")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func didDiscoverPeripheralInt(peripheral: Int) {

        myInts.append(peripheral)
        print("Number = \(myInts.count)")
    }  
}
```

**CustomClass.swift**

```
class CustomClass : NSObject {

    var customClassDelegate : CustomClassDelegate?

    // MARK: init

    override init() {
        super.init()

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "writeInt", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func writeInt () {
        CustomClassDelegate?.didDiscoverPeripheralInt(3)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question shows a bunch of predominantly empty methods - how are they useful? Where are the instances created? When does each class call the others? Provide details related to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I edited AViewController code. The CustomClass instance is created into viewDidLoad method of the MainViewController. The others empty methods is only to understand view controller lifecycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var customClassDelegate : CustomClassDelegate?
```

You are holding a string reference to your delegate.
It needs to be

```
 weak  var customClassDelegate : CustomClassDelegate?
```

Take a look at the following document :
http://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Your `CustomClass` holds strong reference to the delegate. You have to mark the property with `weak`:

```
weak var customClassDelegate : CustomClassDelegate?
```